# About the implicit function theorem

Tags: calculus

Let $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^{k+n}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be of class $C^1$; suppose that $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})=\mathbf{0}$ and that $D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})$ has rank $n$. Show that if $\mathbf{c}$ is a point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ sufficiently close to $\mathbf{0}$, then the equation $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{c}$ has a solution.

Shall I use the Implicit function theorem? If so, can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

That's indeed the Implicit Functions Thm, if one has a good version. In fact, it follows easily from the usual proof of it as a consequence of the Inverse Functions Thm.

We denote $(x,y)$ the coordinates in $\mathbb R^{k+n}=\mathbb R^k\times\mathbb R^n$ and the rank condition  at $a=(\alpha,\beta)$ can be supposed for the $n\times n$ minor $D\ne0$ corresponding to the $y$ variables. Then one defines $F(x,y)=(x,f(x,y))$, whose jacobian determinant at $a$ is precisely the minor $D\ne0$ above; we have $F(a)=(\alpha,0)$. Thus by Inverse Functions, there are open nbhds $U$,$V$ and $W$ of $a,\alpha,0$ and a local inverse $G:V\times W\to U$ of $F$, which means $F(G(v,w))=(v,w)$ for $v\in V, w\in W$; denote $H$ the $y$-component of the mapping $G$. Then, for $c\in W$ (that is, *$c$ close to $0$*) we have
$$
(\alpha,c)=F(G(\alpha,c))=F(\alpha,H(\alpha,c))=(\alpha,f(\alpha,H(\alpha,c))).
$$ 
Thus $c=f(\alpha, H(\alpha,c))$ and $f(x)=c$ has the solution $x=(\alpha, H(\alpha,c))$.

Actually, the solution exists for any $\alpha'\in V$, that is $\alpha'$ close to $\alpha$, as a function of $\alpha'$. Of course this is Implicit Functions for $f(x)=c$.